# Xamarin Realm Migration API/Method/Interface to add/update/delete schema?

Tags: c#, xamarin, realm, realm-mobile-platform, realm-migration

Is there any API/Method/Interface to add/update/delete schema for Real Xamarin?
Scenarios:

1. Update existing class property to make it primary key.
2. Delete existing class property (Primary or normal).
3. Add a new property in existing class.
4. Add new class.
5. Delete existing class.

Comment: https://realm.io/docs/xamarin/latest/#migrations

Comment: @SushiHangover I have gone through this document. I am looking for something like https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#migrations
for updating existing property or schema

Comment: There is no need to do it like the Java version as the model is defined by the classes that are subclassed from `RealmObject`.  Change the model and increment the `SchemaVersion` and your MigrationCallback handler is invoked. "Old" data is available the `Migration` instance

Answer (score 0):

The .NET binding will perform schema migrations automatically. You just need to bump the `SchemaVersion` for destructive changes (e.g. deleting class/property). It is recommended that you set a [`MigrationCallback`](https://realm.io/docs/xamarin/latest/api/reference/Realms.RealmConfiguration.html#Realms_RealmConfiguration_MigrationCallback) to perform the data migration and avoid losing data (e.g. after deleting or renaming a property).